# difficulty in understanding the coding pattern in javascript in this react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The console throws this error .
'Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined'
Here is the code

```
renderBenefits = (policy) => {
    let tempArr = [];
    if (policy.hasOwnProperty('sum_insured')) {
      tempArr.push({
        value: 'Insurance',
      });
    }
    let benefitsArr = policy?.benefits.reduce((finalArr, bene) => {
      finalArr.push({value: bene?.details?.heading});
      return finalArr;
    }, tempArr);
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 27, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
        {benefitsArr.map((benefit) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                width: wp(13000 / 375),
                paddingBottom: 16,
              }}>
              <Image
                source={this.getBenefitImage(benefit.value)}
                style={{width: 24, height: 24}}></Image>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: wp(900 / 375),
                  ...Typography.getTypography(12, '#4A4A4A', 'OpenSans', 0.43),
                }}>
                {benefit.value}
              </Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

I tried understanding this code

```
let benefitsArr = policy?.benefits.reduce((finalArr, bene) => {
      finalArr.push({value: bene?.details?.heading});
      return finalArr;
    }, tempArr);
```

but what is this pattern to access .benefits. I am aware of using && to access but what is this new pattern and where is this code-breaking and why?

Comment: Are you talking about the `policy?.` part?

Answer (score 1):

This is es2020 syntax called optional chaining.  The error is being thrown because `policy.benefits` is undefined.  You can continue the optional chaining by adding a `?` to `benefits`.

```
let benefitsArr = policy?.benefits?.reduce((finalArr, bene) => {
```

This will now result in `undefined` since we already know from the console log that `benefits` is undefined.  This is enough to get you past the error.  But you will need to go up the tree to find out why `policy` doesn't contain the `benefits` property you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates either, `policy` or `policy.benefits` is `undefined`.

The `?.` operator is for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). In your case, basically, it tries to access `policy.benefits`. Normally in JS, if you run `policy.benefits` and if `policy` is `null` or `undefined`, the code will break. Now with the `?`, `policy?.benefits` will return `undefined` instead in case `policy` is `null` or `undefined`.